# Vue Component wont render HTML on browser refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

Before going into my specific issue, I would like to preface I have spent a lot of time researching to see if my situation wasn't unique, and have not found that to be true. I have a very specific issue with not just one component, but multiple ones showing the same behavior. I am using bootstrap-vue and when I navigate to a new component through a `b-nav-item` or `b-dropdown-item`, the component shows in fine upon entry, but when I refresh the browser or navigate to a different component and go back, the component will just show up blank. After much testing I have found this is taking place for some of my components that are children of a parent component themselves. The head scratching part is not every component that isn't a child of a parent of is exhibiting this behavior.

I am not updating any data in these components and all they contain are forms. I don't use any route guards or props or anything like that either. Below is an example of what my router component looks like

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "LandingPage",
      component: LandingPage
    },
    {
      path: "/signup",
      name: "Signup",
      component: Signup
    },
    {
      path: "/login",
      name: "Login",
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: "/storefront",
      name: "Storefront",
      component: Storefront
    },
  ]
```

As you can see the first component seen is the LandingPage and from there all navigation to other parts takes place. Below is the code that shows how this happens.

```
<b-nav pills vertical>
          <h4>
            <b-nav-item v-b-toggle.collapse-upkeep>Tab1</b-nav-item>
          </h4>
          <b-nav pills vertical>
            <b-collapse id="collapse-upkeep" class="ml-3">
              <h5>
                <b-dropdown-item :to="{ name: 'ComponentThatWorksAsIntended' }"
                  >ComponentWithChildComponents</b-dropdown-item
                >
              </h5>
              <h5>
                <b-dropdown-item
                  link-class="text-wrap"
                  :to="{ name: 'ComponentThatIsBlankOnRefresh' }"
                  >MisbehavingComponent</b-dropdown-item
                >
              </h5>
              
            </b-collapse>
          </b-nav>
          <h4 class="mt-3 pt-3">
            <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'ComponentThatWorksAsIntended' }">ComponentWIthChildComponents</b-nav-item>
          </h4>
                    <h4 class="mt-3 pt-3">
            <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'ComponentThatWorksAsIntended' }">ChildComponentThatWorksFine</b-nav-item>
          </h4>
          <h4 class="mt-3 pt-3">
            <b-nav-item :key="$route.fullPath" :to="{ name: 'ComponentThatIsBlankOnRefresh' }">MisbehavingComponent</b-nav-item>
          </h4>
    
          <h4 class="mt-3 pt-3">
            <b-nav-item
              v-b-toggle.collapse-business-directory
              :to="{ name: 'Storefront' }"
              >IsolatedComponentThatStillWorksForSomeReason</b-nav-item
            >
          </h4>
  

</b-nav>
```

I've gone on the vue router site for Vue 2 and didn't find any real help there either. I've tried using the `key` attribute on the `b-nav-item` and that didn't help with rendering the Bootstrap code again on refresh or going back from navigation.

I'd also like to mention that I pass no props to any of the components that would mess up the views from rendering on refresh either. these are just standalone components that have been behaving like this.

Here is a codesandbox to see the setup of my problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-qqy8yx?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: Do you have any error, in the javascript console, after refresing the page ? Also, does your component show up in the dom ? Are the html tag there or no ?

Comment: No error shows, the form that originally was there just doesn't show up anymore after refreshing or navigating back to the component after leaving it..

Comment: Do your components load correctly if you change `mode: "history"` to `mode: "hash"`? If that's the case the problem is you haven't configured your server for history mode. See [example server configurations](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

Comment: @tao unfortunately changing it to hash mode did not fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, without a *runnable* [mcve] (use codesandbox.io or similar) your chances of getting a useful answer are quite low.

Comment: @tao It's hard to reproduce as I'm not sure what's causing it in the first place. The example shown above is the extent of where the code, and subsequently the issue, is at.

Comment: Perhaps it's hard. Or perhaps it's not as hard as you think: you can [import local projects](https://codesandbox.io/docs/importing#import-local-projects-via-cli) in codesandbox.io using their [CLI](https://github.com/codesandbox-app/codesandbox-importers/tree/master/packages/cli). But I'm fairly certain it's nearly impossible for you to get a useful answer without giving the ones who might be able to help you eyes on the bug and means to test any potential fix.

Comment: Your CodeSandbox is incomplete - there is no `router.js` but your `main.js` tries to import it.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks for the catch there. I made the necessary changes and it should all work fine now.

Comment: In the example you posted, you don't seem to use `<router-view>` anywhere. Did you read [Getting started](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#getting-started)?

Comment: Correct, Both ```b-nav-item``` and ```b-dropdown-item``` both support ```<router-view>``` behavior without explicitly needing to use one.

Comment: Refreshing the CodeSandbox several times - all 5 links still render on the screen. But they all point to StoreFront.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Correct, that's how i set it up for the visual example. Having them link to several different components with forms wouldn't help as I havent found the specific issue causing some of my html to not show on refresh. The CodeSandbox was more to show what an example of what things currently look like.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your issue is that once these 5 router links are shown on the screen and you reload the page - they are no longer shown and there is no error in the console, correct?

Comment: I exported the CodeSandbox and tried to run it locally. `vue-template-compiler` and `@vue/cli-plugin-router` are missing from `package.json` and you are mounting App.vue improperly which results in a console error that Vue is invoked without its run-time compiler and thus can not compile the template string. You should use a render function for the root Vue instance. But even with this errors fixed - your issue does not reproduce. The 5 router links are still rendered and visible no matter how many times I reload the page.

Comment: @IVOGELOV My issue is that it's not every router link that I use, but yes with some that's the exact issue that's happening. Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce it either and have been hoping someone who has experienced a similar issue can provide some direction.

Comment: The only reason I can think of that will prevent rendering is a JavaScript exception happening during the render or in one of the lifecycle hooks. But since you said there are no errors in the console - I am out of ideas. You will have to debug it when you catch it.

Comment: @IVOGELOV As far as debugging is concerned I have been using the Dev Tools panel for Vue and in testing out the problem I'm having I notice that for the ones having the issue, the component completely leaves the Dom on refresh. I haven't been able to track down why it's happening yet and will keep investigating and checking the documentation for something I may have missed.